# How do I create a loop that can calculate the number of times a specific number can be fitted in another specific number?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, nested-loops

I am creating a program that shall work like this; First the program reads 
the total volume of a transport (e.g. truck) in cubic meters from the keyboard. Next the program calculates how many bags that can be stored in the truck and 
displays this information.

I always want to use as many big bags as possible, meaning that I want to use as many of the biggest bags as possible, then when they can not fit anymore of the biggest bags I want to store as many of the middle size bags as possible and when they can not store anymore middle sized bags they use the smallest size bags to fill up whatever space is left.

*This is how I am trying to solve this, but the greatest problem remains in the looping or logic part, I don't know how do I loop the things so that I prints out what I want.*

```
    package volumecalc;

import java.util.*;

public class BagObject {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //volume in cubic meter
    int sBag = 10 * 10 * 30;     //Size of the smallest bag
    int mBag = 50 * 100 * 40;    //Size of the middle bag
    int bBag = 100 * 200 * 50;   //Size of the biggest bag
    int transVol;

    public void bag() {
        System.out.println("Enter the current volume of your transport: ");
        transVol = input.nextInt();

        if (transVol > bBag) {
            //Probaly here or more places, I need help
        } else if (transVol < sBag) {
            //Probaly here or more places, I need help
        }

    }

}
```

Main class:

```
    package volumecalc;

import java.util.*;

public class VolumeCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("                THIS PROGRAM WILL CALCULATE THE SPACE (IN cubic centimeter) IN TRANSPORT:\n\n");
        BagObject bo = new BagObject();
        bo.bag();

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a version of the knapsack problem - do let us know if you find a good solution, the whole world's looking for one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @EvanKnowles, maybe not.  It sounds to me like there is only one truck, and it sounds like the truck is characterized only by its volume (i.e., it has no specific shape).  If true, then the question is how many big bags fit in the truck (one integer division), how many medium bags will fit in the remainder (another division), and how many small bags will fit in the second remainder (a third and final division op.)

Comment: james large, you are right. The truck has no specific volume. the volume or size is basically choosen from the user input.

Comment: So, you could calculate the answer without using a loop, just as I described with three integer divisions:  Divide the volume of the truck by the volume of a big bag, and that's the most number of big bags that will fit.  Then figure out how much space is left over (the remainder of the division), and divide that by the volume of a medium bag.  Then figure out _that_ remainder, and divide by the volume of a small bag.

Comment: You only need a loop if this is a homework problem, and your instructor told you specifically to use a loop.  In that case, I fear I would be giving a little too much help if I just showed you the loop.  It would be better to get interactive help from somebody who can look over your shoulder and give you hints while you do the typing.

Comment: james large, I want to solve it. no matter if its loop or not

Comment: I mentioned looping because I thought it's more appropriate to use looping, since I am learning programing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68989/discussion-between-riyana-and-james-large).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
int numbBag, nummBag, numsBag;    
int remainder;

numbBag = transvol / bBag;
remainder = transvol % bBag;

nummBag = remainder / mBag;
remainder %= mBag;

numsBag = remainder / sBag;
```

Assuming the transport has no specific shape.

If you want a loop that is reusable for any number of bags you can do this:

```
const int NUM_BAGS = 3;
//put all your bag sizes here
int[] bags = {bBag, mBag, sBag, /*other bags*/};//Array of bags from largest to smallest
int[] numBags = new int[NUM_BAGS];//Number of each bag in the transport
int remainder = transVol;

for(int varA; varA < NUM_BAGS; varA++)
{
    numBags[varA] = remainder / bags[varA];
    remainder %= bags[varA];
}
```

The number of bBags is in numBags[0], mBags in numBags[1] etc., in order from largest to smallest.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I have the fixed amount of size specified for each bag. what could I do in this case?

Comment: The volumes of the bags are contained within your given values (sBag, mBag, bBag).